# Angular sending API result from one component to another in different route

Tags: angular, routes

I've got a search bar on a component like that

**search-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css'],
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  search: string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.search) {
      return;
    }
    this.data.updateProducts(this.search);
  }
}
```

the receiver component on another route

**searchpage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/interfaces/Product';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchpage',
  templateUrl: './searchpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchpage.component.css'],
})
export class SearchpageComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[];

  constructor(private data: DataService) {
    this.data.products$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.products = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.products$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.products = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

and a data service to update the observable

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from '../interfaces/Product';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private products = new ReplaySubject<Product[]>();
  products$ = this.products.asObservable();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {}

  updateProducts(search: string) {
    this.searchService.getProducts(search).subscribe((response) => {
      this.products.next(response);
    });
  }
}
```

So the issue is that I have that search-bar component on my homepage and on the searchpage component... If I use it on searchpage, it means I do not switch page, it works, it shows me the products on that page... But if I use the search input on homepage, it will use routes and it does not show the results...

What am I missing? thank you

**-----EDIT-----**

Solved the problem, actually I was using ngSubmit, submitting the form... just changed it and created an event on the button instead of the form itself.

Comment: Use Subject instead of reply Subject. And subscribe observable either in constructor or ngOnInit and go for console.log() wether the subscribe method is called or not ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just edited the post, actually was an issue on the submit way of the form.